# Failed to open stream error when require/include is on same line as conditional

Tags: php

Why does this work:

```
if($this->data['showPWPanel']) {
    require_once './ProcesswirePanel.inc';
}
```

But this fails:

```
if($this->data['showPWPanel']) require_once './ProcesswirePanel.inc';
```

with the following error:

```
require_once(./ProcesswirePanel.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It's the same with require, include, and include_once.

I am running php 5.6.6. I don't ever recall having this problem before, but maybe just never tried a conditional and require/include on the one line before? Am I missing something obvious or is this a PHP bug.

Comment: This seems to be a php bug.

Comment: Do the same in a new clean folder. It will work. There might be something wrong with your project.

Answer (score 0):

@Sumit, you're right - there was a bug in the file compiler used in the project such that it wasn't adding the appropriate namespace with the conditional on the one line. Sorry for the confusion!